# How to construct a correct HttpRequest in Salesforce

Tags: http, url, salesforce, httprequest, apex

I am developing an application in Salesforce that should communicate with a server to get some data. the server address is like this http://192.168.115.22/.

this is the HttpRequest object i am constructing in my Apex code is :

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
String username = "myLogin", passwd = "myPassword";
String dataUrl = 'sli=on&fli=on&login=' + username + '&password=' + passwd + 'the rest of data';

request.setMethod('POST');
request.setEndpoint('http://192.168.115.22/Services/getLicenses');
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(dataUrl.length()));
request.setBody(dataUrl);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

But the response i am getting contains this error :

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://192.168.115.22/Licgen/Service/getLicensePackage?

    Access Denied.
```

i don't know what is the problem with the url i am constructing, and when i write the url manually in my navigator i have access to the server.

Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue, in light of having already been added to the whitelist for endpoints, I think has to do with the fact that 192.168 IP addresses denote local IP addresses within a network normally.

It's likely that you can reach it because you're on your network, but Salesforce cannot see your network from the inside.  You would need to use something like ngrok.com which allows you to expose a local machine to an outside available IP address.

You can also find out your router's IP address if you are at home, and port forward to your 192.168.115.22 local machine through it to expose it to the outside world, but I've had a much easier time with ngrok.com for easy integration testing with my applications.

[Some Information On 192.168 addresses](http://trendblog.net/ever-wondered-use-192-168-x-x-ip-addresses-home/)

(Adding this answer because my other answer could legitimately solve someone searching for the same issue above)

Comment: it's strange that `Salesforce` cannot see my network from the inside, because when i was developing a `symfony2 Application` in a local network and the address was http://10.2.30.40 I include it in salesforce remotely without any problem

Comment: I see, well if salesforce can see your intranet then it should have no issue seeing this unless you have different rules on your internal network routing for 192. addresses vs 10. addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may have to do with the fact that Salesforce prevents outside calls to un-authorized endpoints.  Fortunately, it is a simple matter of adding an endpoint to the whitelist of authorized outbound connection points.

Under the `setup` menu option, and then again under teh `security` menu, there is a menu item called `remote site settings`.  Within this option you'll see a list of sites you are allowed to access from within Salesforce.  If your endpoint isn't in the list, add it and you may get a different result.

Please let me know if you have already added this to the whitelist and it is still a problem.

Comment: thank for your answer. I have already added In the remote Site Settings the adress of the server, this problem is related with another thing

Comment: I don't know if it's because the server is protected by `username and password` and the `HttpRequest` is not well formed. if you see my question i inserted the username and the password in the body of the `HttpRequest`.

Comment: When you use 'Incognito' mode within Chrome and try to navigate to the server with the same query-string as Salesforce, you have no problem reaching the server for posting data?  You can test with something like `Postman` as well. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: I have no problem reaching the server, but i have a question:  since my server needs authentication, should i set this property `Authorization` in the header this way : `request.setHeader('Authorization', someauthorization);` ???

Comment: If you can connect and post from any other application using just query-string username and password attributes, then it shouldn't be a problem and you shouldn't require the Authorization header.  

One thing that Postman will be able to help with is in attempting to re-create the issue Salesforce is having as you can set all the HTTP attributes via it i believe and test posting.  Reaching the site via Chrome requires an HTTP get request not a POST request, which may also be treated differently.

Comment: Well, after searching ando doing some tests i realized that your previous answer is correct: the adress is private and Salesforce cannot access to it unless it's a public address. So iam going to mark your anwser as the correct one. Thank you